# What are the best practices for supporting a RichText in an application?

Tags: flutter, xss, quill, richtext

I have a flutter app, and I would like to add a support for RichText for the users.
A user should be able to use a RichText editor when they first create a Post or later when they decided they want to edit the post.

I have chosen to use [flutter_quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) library. It is a great library and fairly easy to work with, the library provides or consumes Delta documents. Delta documents can be easily converted from/to encoded json.

Although Flutter is a mobile development framework, and its apps typically run on mobile devices rather than in a web browser, the flutter_quill package uses web technologies (such as HTML and CSS) to represent the rich text, and it can be vulnerable to XSS attacks in the same way as a web application.

In particular, if I allow users to input arbitrary HTML or JavaScript code, it's important to sanitize the input to prevent malicious code from being injected into the app. This can be done on both the client-side and the server-side.

The flutter_quill package provides some built-in sanitization features to prevent malicious code from being included in the rich text content, but I don't know if I can only rely on that.

So I am looking for the best practices in terms of storage format and security.

Tech stack:

- Client: Flutter app, Dart with Quill
- Server: Nodejs + SQL DB

I have thought about multiple solutions and I listed some of my findings

#### Solution #1

**Storage:** Content will be stored as json in the DB
**Security:** we need to sanitise json before storing to the DB. and sanitise json before using it in Quill in the Client.

**Is saving the content in DB as json a good idea?**

> Storing content as JSON in the DB is a good idea if you plan to use the Quill editor long-term. JSON is a flexible format that can be easily converted to other formats if needed. However, you will need to sanitise the JSON data before storing it in the DB and before using it in the client to avoid security issues. There are some good libraries for JSON sanitization, such as DOMPurify and SafeValue.

**What is the recommended way to sanitise json?**

> Sanitizing JSON can be tricky, as JSON can contain complex data structures. You can use a library like the ones mentioned above to sanitize the data, or you can write your own sanitization function. The main idea is to strip out any dangerous tags or attributes that could be used to execute malicious code.

**Can you give me a list of tags and attributes that are commonly used in XSS attacks**
Tags:

```
<script>
<iframe>
<img>
<object>
<embed>
<video>
<audio>
<svg>
```

Attributes:

```
onload
onerror
onmouseover
onclick
onfocus
onblur
style
href
src
background
data
/>
```

**When I want to sanitise the content on the server side, can I rely on convert to HTML, sanitise the HTML, compare the the HTML before and after sanitisation, and save the content as json only if there are no differences in the comparison?**

> Comparing the HTML before and after sanitization is a good idea to ensure that the sanitization process does not alter the data. However, this will add some overhead to your system, so you need to weigh the benefits of this approach against the extra processing time.

#### Solution #2:

In this solution the Client will convert Delta to HTML, sanitise it and send it to the server. The server then sanitises it again and saves it in the DB.
Later when the Client fetch Posts, the client should sanitise the HTML before rendering it.

**Storage:** Content will be stored as HTML in the DB
**Security:** we need to sanitise HTML before storing to the DB. and sanitise HTML before using it in the Client.

Storing content as HTML in the DB is a good idea if you need to display the content in HTML format frequently. This format is easy to use and can be displayed on most devices without any extra processing. However, you will need to sanitize the HTML data before storing it in the DB and before using it in the client to avoid security issues.

The main issue with this approach is that you cannot directly use HTML with the Quill editor. You will need to convert the HTML to Delta format, which can be complex and time-consuming, and maybe not even possible. If you need to edit the content frequently, you may need to store the content in both HTML and Delta format, which can add extra complexity to your system.

Any ideas and thoughts about these solutions can be much appreciated, I would love to discuss these solutions or any other solution that can offer more practicality and security.